# Issue in applying css on lightning:tab in Aura

Tags: javascript, css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lightning

I want to apply custom CSS on lightning:tab of lightning:tabset I tried using inline CSS, external CSS but there is no luck, I want a way to check below:

**(Used to create tab section which is highlighted)**

```
.THIS li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: dodgerblue !important;
    color: white !important;
    height:1.5rem;
    cursor: no-drop !important;
    pointer-events: none;
    
}
.THIS li:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: dodgerblue !important;
    color: white !important;
    height:1.5rem;
    cursor: no-drop !important;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.THIS li:nth-child(12) {
    background-color: dodgerblue !important;
    color: white !important;
    height:1.5rem;
    cursor: no-drop !important;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.THIS li:nth-child(15) {
    background-color: dodgerblue !important;
    color: white !important;
    height:1.5rem;
    cursor: no-drop !important;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This worked, anyhow I need some other solution as I am **getting tabs dynamically there can be "n" number of tabs**. and updating the CSS on every tab insertion/deletion is Misery!

Please let me know if anyone has any solution

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use !important in your CSS, maybe your .css files are included in the wrong order.
check the element/style section in your browser's developer tools and find the files that are overriding the style of your tables.

Comment: I checked there is no other style overriding the custom Css.

Comment: It's strange, can you see your custom style in dev tools? maybe your style isn't targeting the HTML tags.
Share a screenshot or something.